# Rewrite does not work in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx1.8.0 in windows10, this is the core configuration which I tried to rewrite the request

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    rewrite ^/qt/(\w+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)_(\d+).(\w+)$ /qtfile/$1/$4/$5.$6 last;
    # /qt/zoom/x_plus/y_plus/x_y.type   ==>  /qtfile/zoom/x/y.type


    location /qtfile {
        access_log logs/images.log;
        alias   D:/tiles/;
    }
    location / {
        root   D:/www;
    }
}
```

The link `http://localhost/qtfile/s/214/7645/102.jpg` will return the right image, however the link `http://localhost/qt/s/214/323/34254/7645_102.jpg` will throw error:

```
2015/10/10 10:40:09 [error] 1420#11676: *1 CreateFile() "D:/www/qt/s/214/323/34254/7645_102.jpg" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /qt/s/214/323/34254/7645_102.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

It seems that the request is catched by the `loation /` segment.

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your regex isn't correct for the input. You gave the example `http://localhost/qt/s/214/323/34254/7645_102.jpg` with the regex `^/qt/(\w+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)_(\d+).(\w+)$`. You only have two number segments in your regex, but three in the URL.

Based on the URL, your regex should be:

```
^/qt/(\w+)/\d+/\d+/\d+/(\d+)_(\d+).(\w+)$
```

You'll have to adjust the second part of the rewrite to be

```
/qtfile/$1/$2/$3.$4
```